# dropdown menu with input

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like when I click on an element, the element must be placed into my input. But I don't know how to do it ?

```
<div class="control-group span3 offset3 ">

    <div class="input-append btn-group">
        <input  id="appendedInputButton"  type="text">
        <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <!-- ko foreach: $data.phoneNumbers() -->
            <li><span data-bind="text: $data.phoneNumber()"></span> </li>
             <!-- /ko -->
        </ul>
    </div>
```

http://imageup.fr/uploads/1377857115.jpeg

Answer (score 4):

Use some JQuery its fairly simple, first include the library if its not already included:

`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Then add your function:

## JQuery:

```
$(".dropdown-menu li span" ).click(function() {
  $('#appendedInputButton').val($(this).text());
});
```

## [JSfiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/b7ymw/)

Comment: Whoever down-voted this, can I ask why you did when it is infact the correct answer and both other answers were just an exact replica of it?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.dropdown-menu li').on('click', function(){
    $('#appendedInputButton').val($(this).text());
});
```

This jquery function will take the clicked drop down menu item and place it in your input box

Answer (score 0):

Check out the demo I think your trying to do this only **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aWQAS/1/)**

```
 $('.dropdown-menu li span').click(function(){
    var elementVal=$(this).text();
    $('#appendedInputButton').val(elementVal);
 });
```

Comment: @user2706463 you can say thanks by upvoting my answer :) I recommend you to read more about jquery here http://www.jquery4u.com/ http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp